# Fixing alignment with the rest of the text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, align

[image]

The image included above is what I want to replicate - I want the name to appear on the top left, and the address/email-id to appear on the top right, and I want both of them to be aligned with the body of the text.

The following is my attempt at it (the blah blah text is there to demonstrate the alignment problem) -

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}

\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } l r }
  \huge{\textbf{John Doe}} & Qtr D/40, Unit 12, Upper Kolkata\\
                           & (011) 2040-3455 john@duh.com\\
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!10]
\bigskip
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \
\bigskip
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\linewidth}

\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\linewidth}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah      
blah blah blah
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

And what I get out of it is this -

[image]

As can be seen, the address/email-id text on the right overflows and exceed the text margin for the rest of the document.

How do I fix it? Also, is it a good idea to use tables for this kind of layout? What is a good alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're specifying `\textwidth` for the name line at the top, and everything else uses `\linewidth`.  one would think the same dimension register should be used for both.

Comment: That \textwidth is actually a leftover from my experiments, sorry about that. I tried \linewidth too, but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the minipage. When I put more text below it, it gets aligned with the address/email-id, and not the minipages. So I guess we have to fix the alignment of the minipages. Will I be correct to assume that the geometry package doesn't affect the alignment of minipages?

Comment: a table gets set like a big letter and that is the start of a paragraph so indented by `\parindent` put `\noindent` before it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest avoiding explicit mark up, which is tedious and error prone.

My realization of the header uses `tabular*` with two nested `tabular` environment that ensure vertical centering as in the original.

For the personal data, I suggest a `data` environment that contains both the left part and the right part, each prefixed by the corresponding commands. The width of the right part is computed once and for all at the beginning of the document and the width of the left part is computed accordingly, leaving some predetermined space (here two ems).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}

\newsavebox{\databox}
\newlength{\datawidth}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \sbox{\databox}{%
    \leftpart Mock text
    \end{mdframed}\end{minipage}}
  \setlength{\datawidth}{\wd\databox}
}
\newenvironment{data}
 {\noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\par}
\newcommand{\leftpart}{%
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \begin{mdframed}[
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
    innertopmargin=\bigskipamount,
    innerbottommargin=\bigskipamount]}
\newcommand{\rightpart}{%
  \end{mdframed}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\datawidth}}


\begin{document}

\noindent%%% remember this
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } l r@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \huge\bfseries John Doe
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Qtr D/40, Unit 12, Upper Kolkata\\
  (011) 2040-3455 john@duh.com
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\begin{data}
\leftpart
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\rightpart

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah      
blah blah blah
\end{data} 

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option is of course just for this example. Never use the obsolete `a4wide` package.

[image]